# Working with TLVs in ctypes

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

I'm new to ctypes,so my questions are:

1) What's the correct way to declare [TLVs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) in ctypes?:
The TLV's fields are as follows:

> TAG (2 bytes) | LENGTH (2 bytes) | DATA (variable length)

Is the declaration below correct?

> class Tlv(Structure):   _fields = [("tag",c_ushort),
>                ("len",c_ushort),
>              ("data",POINTER(c_ubytes))             ]

2) The client and the server exchange messages that have the following structure:

> HEADER (including data length) | DATA (byte buffer composed of TLVs)

How do I read (parse) the byte buffer into TLVs in ctypes?

Comment: Struct's `data` field should be *BYTE: `("data",POINTER(c_ubyte))` (the __s__ is gone, i don't know if it was there intentionally or by mistake).

Comment: That's a typo,certainly.

Comment: The buffer will typically be packed (`_pack_ = 1`) and big endian (`BigEndianStructure`). Define `Header` and copy it from the buffer as `offset = 0;` `header = Header.from_buffer_copy(buf, offset)`.Then increment `offset += sizeof(header)`, and loop to grab the TLVs. In the loop, get `tlv_header = TLVHeader.from_buffer_copy(buf, offset)` and increment `offset += sizeof(tlv_header)`. Then get `data = (dtype_from_tag * length).from_buffer_copy(buf, offset)` and increment `offset += sizeof(data)`. Repeat `while offset < len(buf)`. You can also use the `struct` module for this.

Comment: Thanx,I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: If you run into a problem implementing this, you can revise your question with what you've tried, to be more specifically answerable.